# Combining GROUP BY and CASE expressions - Labelling Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been struggling to use `CASE` expressions within `GROUP BY`. I'm not sure if this is the best way to query what I want - so please let me know if there's a better way to do this - but this is the closest I can get. The problem I'm running into now is labelling the `GROUP BY` statement.

```
ID      Crossing_Order     Barhab_Weighted
1             0                 120
2             0                 0
3             1                 200
4             1                 500
5             2                 200
6             3                 10
7             4                 500
```

And would love to get a table like this:

```
Crossing_Order       Over_100            Under_100
zero                    1                   1   
one                     0                   2
more_than_1             1                   2
```

This code gets me close:

```
SELECT
count(distinct(case when a.barhab_weighted > 100 then site_id end)) as Over_100
,count(distinct(case when a.barhab_weighted <= 100 then site_id end)) as Under_100

FROM site_details as a

GROUP BY case
when a.crossing_order = 0 then 'zero'
when a.crossing_order = 1 then 'one'
when a.crossing_order > 1 then 'more_than_1' end
```

The result I get is close, but I can't get it to label correctly. How do I get the 'zero' and 'one' values to show up?

```
         Over_100       Under_100
1           1               1
2           0               2
3           1               2
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function! Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `count(distinct case when a.barhab_weighted > 100 then site_id end)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Add your case statement from your group by as a column.

Comment: @JacobH "case expression" - its not a statement :)

Comment: @DaleK Sequel or es queue ell? :) You are right, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `count(distinct)` on a unique column.

But you need the `CASE` logic in the `SELECT`.  This is simplest if you define it once using a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.Crossing_Order,
       count(distinct case when sd.barhab_weighted > 100 then sd.site_id end)) as Over_100,
       count(distinct case when sd.barhab_weighted <= 100 then sd.site_id end)) as Under_100
FROM site_details sd CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (case when sd.crossing_order = 0 then 'zero'
                   when sd.crossing_order = 1 then 'one'
                   when sd.crossing_order > 1 then 'more_than_1'
              end)
     ) v(Crossing_Order)
GROUP BY v.Crossing_Order;
```

Note that I also changed the table alias `a` to something meaningful -- `sd` -- an abbreviation for the table.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` does not add fields to the results, you need to `SELECT` that case expression, and repeat it in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN a.crossing_order = 0 THEN 'zero'
      WHEN a.crossing_order = 1 THEN 'one'
      WHEN a.crossing_order > 1 THEN 'more_than_1' 
   END AS crossing_order
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.barhab_weighted > 100 THEN site_id END) AS Over_100
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.barhab_weighted <= 100 THEN site_id END) AS Under_100
FROM site_details AS a
GROUP BY CASE WHEN a.crossing_order = 0 THEN 'zero'
   WHEN a.crossing_order = 1 THEN 'one'
   WHEN a.crossing_order > 1 THEN 'more_than_1' 
   END
```

Note: If you actually want the data in the order you presented, you may need another CASE expression to convert the cross_order "when"s to appropriate values; otherwise "zero" will order last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select
    case
        when a.crossing_order = 0 then 'zero'
        when a.crossing_order = 1 then 'one'
        when a.crossing_order > 1 then 'more_than_1' 
    end cat,
    sum(case when barhab_weighted >= 100 then 1 else 0 end) over_100,
    sum(case when barhab_weighted <  100 then 1 else 0 end) under_100
from site_details
group by
    case
        when a.crossing_order = 0 then 'zero'
        when a.crossing_order = 1 then 'one'
        when a.crossing_order > 1 then 'more_than_1' 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `case` to group crossing_order in a derived table. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select crossing_order_grouped,
       count(distinct case when barhab_weighted > 100 then site_id end) as Over_100,
       count(distinct case when barhab_weighted <= 100 then site_id end) as Under_100
from
(
    SELECT case when crossing_order = 0 then 'zero'
                when crossing_order = 1 then 'one'
                when crossing_order > 1 then 'more_than_1'
           end crossing_order_grouped,
           Barhab_Weighted
    from site_details
) dt
group by crossing_order_grouped
```